# Best approach to make a login screen

Tags: android

I am writing here because this is my last solution of understanding this type of programming.The problem is that I got stuck on what to use to handle the connection to a server and log-in. Should I use async task, handler or thread ? I didn't find a concrete answer stating which one to use, only found that async task is used to download images or other download stuffs.

Until now I have used a thread to connect to the server. The problem  I encountered was when I catch the exception ( Putting invalid username/password ) and try to log-in again. ( I needed to "close" the last thread and start one again )

After this I started to use async task but I don't really understand how it should work and I am stuck on a toast of invalid username/password.

```
private class connectStorage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            api = DefaultClientFactory.create(host, getUser, getPassword);
            if (api.getAuthToken().trim().length() > 3) {
                //TO DO LAYOUT CHANGE;
            }
        } catch (StorageApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("TEST", "" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Also, I am 100% sure that calling inflate in the `doInBackground` method won't work too ( there I wanted to change the activity ).

I am starting the async task on a button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using asynctask
You have doInBackground and onPostExecute
So basically get a json or string or boolean as a result from doinbackground
and in onpostexecute check if the login in succesful or not if its succesful save the data from server and start an intent to go to another activity or toast the user that that user login details are wrong and try again.

So your asynctask can be an inner class of your activity class which is login and onClickSubmit button call the asynctask class and on post execute parse the json and according to the result decide what to do

Example:

```
    public class SignInAsycTask extends AsyncTask<RequestParams, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(RequestParams... params) {
        return new HttpManager().sendUserData(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String[] details = parseJsonObject(result);
        if (details != null) {
            user.setUser_id(Integer.valueOf(details[0]));
            user.setName(details[1]);
            if (details.length > 2) {
                user.setProfilePic(details[2]);
            }
            setSharedPreferences();
            startActivity(new Intent(Signin.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

public String[] parseJsonObject(String result) {
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(result);
        if (obj.has("success")) {
            if (obj.getInt("success") == 1) {
                if (obj.has("user_pic")) {
                    return new String[] {
                            String.valueOf(obj.getInt("user_id")),
                            obj.getString("user_name"),
                            obj.getString("user_pic") };
                } else {
                    return new String[] {
                            String.valueOf(obj.getInt("user_id")),
                            obj.getString("user_name"), };
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

here my RequestParams are just a object where I stored all the details like url parameters to send etc and the output of the doinbackground is a String and I am parsing it in my postexecute method